# Access the element of array property in a generic list via C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, generics

How do I get items which equal to an input value from a generic list?

for example,

```
class Example {
   string stringFiled;
   string[] arrayFiled; // the length of array is fixed
}

Assumption: if the field name contains "array", it will be an array.
```

I have a generic filter function to filter the list by the field name and an input keyword.

Assume that we only care about index 1 when we access array field.

I only can finish partial function.

Could you help me to access the array property?

```
 public List<T> Filter(List<T> src, string field, string keyword) {

     if (field.Contains("array")) {

       // Don't know how to do access the array property in generic list

     } else {
       list = list.where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(x).ToString().Contains(keyword)).Select(x => x).ToList();
     }
     return list;
 }
```

Comment: How do you know that `T` has an array property and what it is called? You could constraint `T` to be of some type that has an array property. But please clarify your question and code sample.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Here I made an assumption, if the field name contains "array" and it will be an array. So there is an if condition in the function.

Comment: You're using `GetProperty()`, but your example has Fields instead of properties. Which are you trying to support?

Comment: The user will input the field name as a parameter (Assume that user always inputs valid field name), and the function can use GetProperty(field name) to get the field.

Comment: `GetProperty()` gets _properties_ whereas `GetField()` gets _fields_. Those are two different concepts in .NET.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Select(x => x)`?

Comment: Select(x =>x) is meaningless, I should take it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<T> Filter<T>(List<T> src, string field, string keyword)
{
    var reflectedField = typeof(T).GetField(field);
    var fieldType = reflectedField.FieldType;
    if (fieldType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable<string>)))
    {
        
        // Don't know how to do access the array property in generic list
        return src.Where(x => ((IEnumerable<string>)reflectedField.GetValue(x)).Any(v => v.Contains(keyword))).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return src.Where(x => reflectedField.GetValue(x).ToString().Contains(keyword)).ToList();
    }
}
```

- I'm assuming you intend to get *fields* rather than *properties*, but it would be relatively easy to change this code to get properties, or even to handle both properties and fields.
- Rather than requiring the name to follow a specific pattern, this will be based on the declared type of the field. If it implements `IEnumerable<string>` (which includes arrays and lists), then it'll get picked up.
- I'm assuming you want this to match an item in the list where *any* of the strings in the array field *contain* the keyword. If you want them to be *equal to* the keyword, change the `Contains` criteria to `==` or `Equals`.
- `.Select(x => x)` is always a no-op. Get rid of that dead code.

Comment: Actually, it isn't in one particular case - when you are working with an `IGrouping` and want to return an `IEnumerable<T>` instead.

Comment: Thanks, your solution helps me a lot

Comment: @NetMage: If you're referring to my last bullet point, `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>` already implements `IEnumerable<TValue>`, so you can either rely on a cast (explicit or implicit) or call `.AsEnumerable()` for that. There's still no point using `.Select(x => x)`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior `AsEnumerable()` is just a cast to the interface on `IGrouping` and doesn't really prevent access to `.Key`. `.Select(x => x)` actually prevents any use of the source type of the `IEnumerable<T>` (e.g. such as `IList` optimizations).

Comment: That's sort of true. Code could often use reflection to access the private members, so if you're relying on that obfuscation for security or something you need to control the trust level that you're executing in, and I'd also argue for using a wrapper type explicitly designed for that purpose rather than `.Select(x => x)`, to make the _intent_ of your code clear. In most cases (e.g. `IList` optimizations), you'd _benefit_ from letting code know a little more about your implementation. (LINQ code probably optimizes it anyway, via interfaces implemented by the object returned from Select.)